# Html as string on MVC5 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently, I store Html in database and populate into a Dropdownlist like this I'm using @funcion in Razor:

```
private string getHtmlTemplate()
{
    string value = "<select id='htmlTemplate'><option value=''>Html Template</option>";
    int i = 0;
    foreach (AdminHtmlTemplateModel htmlTemplateModel in Model.GetAdminHtmlTemplates())
    {
        value += string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", htmlTemplateModel.templateCode, htmlTemplateModel.templateName);
        //value += string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", i++, htmlTemplateModel.templateName);
        templateCodes.Add(htmlTemplateModel.templateCode);
    }

    value += "</select>";
    return value;
}
```

The problem is Html that was stored on templateCode was conflicted/merged with current html file
[image]
How to resolve this issue, I still want those Html value to work work with Editor.
I try some way like as on value of option tag just passing index and on function:

```
@fucntion{
 private string getHtmlTemplate()
{
    string value = "<select id='htmlTemplate'><option value=''>Html Template</option>";
    int i = 0;
    foreach (AdminHtmlTemplateModel htmlTemplateModel in Model.GetAdminHtmlTemplates())
    {
        value += string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", i++, htmlTemplateModel.templateName);
    }

    value += "</select>";
    return value;
 }
}

<script>
$("#htmlTemplate").kendoDropDownList({
        change: function (e) {
            editor.exec("inserthtml", { value:@Model.GetAdminHtmlTemplateCodeByIndex(@:e.sender.value()) });
        }
    });
</script>
```

But it won't work because we can't pass jquery value of razor to function, right?

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Why not replace " with '  ?

Comment: Put the template in a partial view and load that via JS

Comment: Have you every tried `@Html.Encode()`?

Comment: I found that I can use javascript escape/unescape to encode/decode Html value inside Razor but the main issue is when using with CustomControl of KendoUI MVC Editor, it doesn't allow insert Html into Editor. Thanks guys for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,
After few hours to research, I found that I can use snippets to resolve my issue instead of use CustomControl in Kendo UI MVC.

```
private List<AdminHtmlTemplateModel> getHtmlTemplate()
{
    ////string value = "<select id='htmlTemplate'><option value=''>Html Template</option>";
    ////int i = 0;
    ////foreach (AdminHtmlTemplateModel htmlTemplateModel in Model.GetAdminHtmlTemplates())
    ////{
    ////    //value += string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", htmlTemplateModel.templateCode, htmlTemplateModel.templateName);
    ////    value += string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", i++, htmlTemplateModel.templateName);
    ////    templateCodes.Add(htmlTemplateModel.templateCode);
    ////}

    ////value += "</select>";
    ////return value;
    return Model.GetAdminHtmlTemplates();
}

@(Html.Kendo().Editor().Enccode(false)
                                              .Name("EmailBody")
                                              .Tools(tools => tools
                                                  .ViewHtml()
//.CustomTemplate(ct => ct.Template(getHtmlTemplate())) // before
.Snippets(s => //after fixed
{ 
    foreach (var item in getHtmlTemplate())
   {
        s.Add(item.templateName, item.templateCode);
    }
})
```

That's all. And it resolve my problem to insertHtml inside Kendo UI MVC Editor.